# Set a button background image iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, button

In Xcode, how do you set the background of a `UIButton` as an image? Or, how can you set a background gradient in the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Complete code:

```
+ (UIButton *)buttonWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                       target:(id)target
                     selector:(SEL)selector
                        frame:(CGRect)frame
                        image:(UIImage *)image
                 imagePressed:(UIImage *)imagePressed
                darkTextColor:(BOOL)darkTextColor
{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    UIImage *newImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *newPressedImage = [imagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newPressedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return button;
}

UIImage *buttonBackground = UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png";
UIImage *buttonBackgroundPressed = UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png";

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kStdButtonWidth, kStdButtonHeight);

UIButton *button = [FinishedStatsView buttonWithTitle:title
                                               target:target
                                             selector:action
                                                frame:frame
                                                image:buttonBackground
                                         imagePressed:buttonBackgroundPressed
                                        darkTextColor:YES];

[self addSubview:button];
```

To set an image:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

To remove an image:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Why do you create a copy of an image before setting the button's BG to that image? Do we risk memory leaks or unusual behavior if we don't, or is it just to allow images to stretch to fill their buttons?

Answer (score 17):

This will work

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
[btn setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone `setBackgroundImage` didn't work for me, but `setImage` did

Comment: with setImage you set the foreground Image... if you want to set the background image use setBackgroundImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>

Answer (score 3):

You can set an background image without any code!

Just press the button you want an image to in **Main.storyboard**, then, in the **utilities** bar to the right, press the **attributes inspector** and set the background to the image you want! 
Make sure you have the picture you want in the **supporting files** to the left.

Answer (score 2):

When setting an image in a `tableViewCell` or `collectionViewCell`, this worked for me:

Place the following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

// Obtain pointer to cell. Answer assumes that you've done this, but here for completeness.

```
CheeseCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cheeseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

// Grab the image from document library and set it to the cell.

```
UIImage *myCheese = [UIImage imageNamed:@"swissCheese.png"];
[cell.cheeseThumbnail setImage:myCheese forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**NOTE:** xCode seemed to get hung up on this for me. I had to restart both xCode and the Simulator, it worked properly.

This assumes that you've got cheeseThumbnail set up as an IBOutlet... and some other stuff... hopefully you're familiar enough with table/collection views and can fit this in.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

Set the button image like this:

```
let myImage = UIImage(named: "myImageName")
myButton.setImage(myImage , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

where `myImageName` is the name of your image in your asset catalog.

Answer (score 0):

In one line we can set image with this code

```
[buttonName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for background image of a Button in **Swift 3.0**

`buttonName.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "facebook.png"), for: .normal)`

Hope this will help someone.