# Set Button title in two different colors in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uicolor

I want to set title on Button in two colors.

Is it possible same as given image below ?

[image: Button in 2 colors]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use attributed Text for title..

Comment: @MidhunMP: No, I'll get text from web-service. So, can't set as an image.

Comment: You can use image with text for button

Comment: Yes add the Image as backgroundImage of UIButton

Comment: It would be very easy to put image rather than coloring the text...

Comment: @iManan: Use attributed text and coretext

Comment: @JayGajjar: As, I mentioned I get response from web-service. So I can't set as image.

Comment: What you can do is download the image via websevices in binary format and then save the image on the device. Thus your web service will called once and then your image will be loaded form cell itself

Comment: @iManan: I also want pretty same solution for ios version less than 6.0. I have also tried `CTFontRef` but with no success. Please let me know if you found any one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This is what you need**

```
  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  btn.frame = CGRectMake(5,10,300,20);
  [self.view addSubview:btn];

  NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"100 Photos"]];
  [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
  [btn setAttributedTitle:attrStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @iManan- what is your targhet os

Comment: for Xamarin use UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor as attributename NSString

Answer (score 13):

In storyBoard : Follow the ScreenShot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For Programmatically : There are already many answers posts over here for **attributed text** and If you want to put **BackgroundImage for UIButton** [Set a button background image iPhone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723831/set-a-button-background-image-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: KI: Can I set programatically after fetching record from web-service response.?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I didn't realize I had to highlight the text in the box to get the color to change. Could not figure out why my set colors didn't work!

Answer (score 3):

For swift 3:

```
let button = UIButton()
let mainTitle = "200"
let subtitle = "Members"

let attrText1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: mainTitle)
attrText1.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: 15, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrText1.length))
attrText1.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrText1.length))


let attrText2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: subtitle)
attrText2.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: 15, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrText2.length))
attrText2.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrText2.length))

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
attributedText.append(attrText1)
attributedText.append(attrText2)

//Center align
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributedText.length))

button.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"ThisIsAttributed"];
[mutableString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,4)];
[mutableString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor]  range:NSMakeRange(5,2)];
[button setAttributedTitle:mutableString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[button setAttributedTitle:someAttributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [for ios below 5.0](http://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)
 and `NSMutableAttributedString` for current ios versions.