# Multi color text in Xamarin Forms Button

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I had a requirement to have multi color text as xamarin forms button which is targeted for IOS, Android and in future for Win 10 application. Xamarin Forms button control does not support this out of box and would need some customization.

here is sample button image expected.
[image]

Comment: Please see [the solution without custom renderers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824184/dynamic-ui-in-xamarin-forms/41345666#41345666) It is a solid border, not a cornered though :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually make a stacklayout with the design, and make it clickable in the backend like so:

```
<StackLayout Margin="1" BackgroundColor="Black" Widthrequest="100" HeightRequest="50">
    <Stacklayout BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="yourButtonControl" Widthrequest="100" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5" HeightRequest="50">
        <Image Source="your image path" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        <Label HorizontalOptions="End">your text</Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

make that StackLayout clickable:

```
var tapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapped.Tapped += clickedEvent;
yourButtonControl.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapped);
```

Your event:

```
public void clickedEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e){

}
```

Comment: It should have look and feel like buttons. Stacklayout does not have borders. Also, I need to add it in listview row.

Comment: you can recreate the border by wrapping inside another stacklayout with a margin (what you want the border width to be ) and adding a background color to show out the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Image` property on a [button](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Button/#Public_Properties)?

So you would have the following:

```
<Button Text="Text" Image="Tick.png"/>
```

And you could design your own (or buy) a checkmark graphic like the one shown [here](http://findicons.com/files/icons/2625/google_plus_interface_icons/128/checkmark2.png):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom render for Button. 
Both iOS and Android support buttons with both image and text. Windows does not and that is why its not supported in Forms out of the box.

Please find sample of iOS renderer :

```
public class DashboardButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    private const int ImageSize = 25;

    private UIButton _button;
    private DashboardButton _dashboardButton;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e?.OldElement == null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _button = Control;
            e.NewElement.BorderRadius = 0;
            _dashboardButton = (DashboardButton)e.NewElement;
            _button.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((nfloat)_dashboardButton.FontSize, UIFontWeight.Semibold);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (e?.PropertyName == DashboardButton.BadgeCountProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            AddBadgeToButton(_dashboardButton.BadgeCount);
        }
        if (e?.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            _button.Enabled = _dashboardButton.IsEnabled;
        }            
    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_dashboardButton?.ButtonImage))
        {
            return;
        }
        SetImage();     //Moved from ondraw to handle Device Orientation Change
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        Control.HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }

    private void SetImage()
    {
        CGSize labelSize = Sizing.GetStringSize(_dashboardButton.Text, (float)_dashboardButton.FontSize, 0f, 0f, UIFontWeight.Semibold);

        UIImage image = new UIImage(_dashboardButton.ButtonImage);
        _button.SetTitle(_dashboardButton.Text, UIControlState.Normal);
        image = ImageHelper.ResizeImage(image, ImageSize, ImageSize);
        _button.SetImage(image, UIControlState.Normal);
        _button.TintColor = UIColor.Gray;

        var imageAllottedSpaceCenterY = (Control.Frame.Size.Height - _button.TitleLabel.Frame.Size.Height) / 2;

        var imageInsetTopBottom = imageAllottedSpaceCenterY - ImageSize / 2;
        var imageInsetLeftRight = Control.Frame.Size.Width / 2 - ImageSize / 2;

        var labelInsetBottom = (Control.Frame.Size.Height - ImageSize) / 2 - _button.Frame.Height / 2;
        var labelInsetLeftRight = _button.Frame.Width / 2 - labelSize.Width / 2;

        _button.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(imageInsetTopBottom, imageInsetLeftRight, imageInsetTopBottom, imageInsetLeftRight);

        var labelInsetRight = Device.Idiom != TargetIdiom.Phone ? labelInsetLeftRight + GetLabelLeftOffset(_dashboardButton.Text) : labelInsetLeftRight;

        _button.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(labelInsetBottom + imageInsetTopBottom + 30
        , labelInsetLeftRight - labelSize.Width / 2 + GetLabelLeftOffset(_dashboardButton.Text)
        , labelInsetBottom, labelInsetRight);
        AddBadgeToButton(_dashboardButton.BadgeCount);
        _button.TintColor = AgvanceColors.TintColor.ToUIColor();
    }        
}
```

If all you need to set is the text of the button in multi color then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17340677/1155650) solution for iOS.

Comment: Could you please provide sample working code. I had challenge in custom renderer for this scenario.

Comment: What was your issue? I have added an iOS sample.

Comment: my challenge was to have multi color text using button renderers for IOS and Android.

Comment: Your first item is an image and then a text?

Comment: That is one of the requirement. I can use FontAwesom Icons for these images so that can be used as text. So, If I get a way to have a multi color text in button for Android & IOS, I am good.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for absolute layout since I can position the elements in the layout exactly what I wanted to.  Just add a transparent button on the top of the layout so the whole layout acts like a button

```
<AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="150">
    <Image Source="Check.png"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0"/>
    <Label Text="TEXT"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.9, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0"/>
    <Button Clicked="ButtonClicked" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="2"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

And the event

```
public void ButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // do something
}
```