# How can I set background image using xml file like android ?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to create a  button with the background. But I want to set using the xml file as same like android have.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: learn iOS as a new platform rather than thinking how to port code. you will have higher chances of success

Comment: @Hitendra plz c my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you cannot directly port your Android specifics or liberties in XCode/Objective-C. You must learn atleast the basics.

For your specific query, you can use the following answer

[Set a button background image iPhone programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723831/set-a-button-background-image-iphone-programmatically)

Also, I would firmly suggest you start learning Objective-C. There are ample resources out there:

1. [APPLE](http://developer.apple.com).
2. [Ray Wenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com)
3. [Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/)
4. [iPhone Dev SDK](http://iphonedevsdk.com/)
5. [Geeky Lemon](http://geekylemon.com)

and many many many more ...